# Word macros to resize a picture to its original size and then back to "thumbnail" size

Tags: microsoft-word, images, macros

Workflow:
1. Insert a larger picture in a MS Word 2010 document
2. Reduce the picture size to a smaller "thumbnail" size
3. Save and close the document
4. Reopen the document
5. Select the picture "thumbnail"
6. Click an icon on the quick access toolbar which starts a macro which enlarges the selected picture to its larger **ORIGINAL SIZE**
7. Click another macro icon to reduce the size of the selected picture to a predefined smaller "Thumbnail" size

Does anybody know existing Word macros to perform steps 6 and 7 in the above workflow? If not, how could such a macro look like?

Comment: You want to be able to resize an image without any loss in the resolution, within word? And have a macro that will focus and unfocus the image?

Comment: @Raystafarian First question: Resetting to original size does not include loss of resolution. Second question: That was not part of my question.

Comment: So what have you tried already? Where are you stuck? Can you get both images to be in the document at the same time? Are you having trouble hiding them?